# ggplot2 clustering in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

can someone point me in the right direction to making a plot like this one w/ ggplot2? even just the function type.

I've been looking around in ggplot2 and can't find anything like this.

Comment: Can you specify which are the essential features of the plot you are trying to create? (For instance: do you care about color? About the 'jitter' on the points? etc.)

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that the essential features of the plot are that:
a.) the x-axis is categorical, and
b.) the x-positions of the points are varied slightly,
c.) some summary statistic (I used medians).
If that's what you're looking for,

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)

#define the data
lev <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels=c("I", "II"))
y <- runif(20)
df <- data.frame(lev, y)

#calculate the medians - I'm guessing that's what the horiz lines are?
meds <- ddply(df, .(lev), summarise, med = median(y))

ggplot(df, aes(x=lev, y=y, colour=lev)) + 
  geom_point(position="jitter") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "darkblue")) +
  geom_errorbar(data=meds, aes(x=lev, y=med, ymin=med, ymax=med))
```

You can use `annotate()` to add the numbers and the little bracket if that is important.
[image]

Comment: this looks great, but is there anyway to cluster the dots more, like a hybrid of jitter and center?

Comment: Replace `position="jitter"` with `position=position_jitter(width=0.05)`. You might then want to adjust the with of the error bars similarly; `geom_errorbar(width=0.1, aes(...`

Comment: Very nice! For as few as points as this (and to make it more regular as @Doug seems to want), I would suggest using `geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")` instead of geom_point with jitter. The [docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_dotplot.html) have some nice examples with very similar data.